Staging ground question title display issues
Question titles in staging-ground can display below the review sidebar when they contain long strings.

Link to the question in the screenshot: https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78583657
This happens for me on

Chrome 125.0.6422.142 (64-bit) on Windows 11
Edge 125.0.2535.85 (64-bit) on Windows 11
Opera 110.0.5130.66 on Windows 11
Chrome 121.0.6167.85 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04

It displays fine on

Firefox 126.0.1 (64-bit) on Windows 11
Firefox 126.0.1 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04



I can't replicate in Firefox 126.0.1. You should include your browser and version number in your post. Also do you have any user scripts enabled on the site?

@ThomA True, I have updated my question to include that information.

@ThomA No, I am not using any user script.

Chrome, Edge and Opera are all Chromium based, so appears to be a Chromium related issue. I don't have Safari installed to test that.

I can reproduce on Safari Version 17.5 (19618.2.12.11.6).

A fix was deployed for this a while back but we forgot to update the status of this post. The question title should now wrap properly to a new line.
